# Unreachable Code Detected Warning with Regex

Tags: c#, unreachable-code

I am fairly new to C#, and feel like this is probably an obvious answer, since I understand what the error means--but I cannot for the life of me see how to fix it! I am getting an "unreachable code detected" warning for my second if statement, so I realize it is not being called, I just don't understand where my error is, or how to go about fixing it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The snippet of code I am having the issue with is:

```
bool valid = true;
if (txtFirst.Text.Length < 1 || txtLast.Text.Length < 1 || txtAddress.Text.Length < 1 || txtCity.Text.Length < 1 || txtState.Text.Length < 1)
{
    return false;
}

string usZip = @"^\d{5}$|^\d{5}-\d{4}$";
Regex re = new Regex(usZip);

return re.IsMatch(txtZip.Text);

if (re.IsMatch(txtZip.Text))
    return (true);
else
    return (false);
return valid;
valid = false;
```

Comment: You are returning right above the second if statement unconditionally: `return re.IsMatch(txtZip.Text);`. Anything below that return won't be reached.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You have a return statement prior to your second if statement:

```
return re.IsMatch(txtZip.Text);
```

So the code below will never execute.

Additionally, you also have unreachable code below your second if, as that if statement will return a value in either case, so:

```
return value;
valid=false;
```

Will never execute either.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check all the field should be field and then if ZIP match the pattern return **TRUE** else **FALSE**  below code is sufficient..

because of your return statement before **if/else** is the reason of unreachable code.. because that return will always has **true OR false** value to return so it will never reach to the **IF/ELSE** condition..

**I think below code is what you want.. check it out..**

```
    if (txtFirst.Text.Length < 1 || txtLast.Text.Length < 1 || txtAddress.Text.Length < 1 || txtCity.Text.Length < 1 || txtState.Text.Length < 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    string usZip = @"^\d{5}$|^\d{5}-\d{4}$";
    Regex re = new Regex(usZip);
    return re.IsMatch(txtZip.Text);
```